# Kendo Grid TemplateFooter aggregation isn't refreshed after applying filters

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo jQuery.

I am creating a grid from a JSON containing floats formatted as string. I'm using a custom function to aggregate a column of my grid. When the grid first loads, there's no problem, my data are aggregate and the sum is correct.

However, when I apply a filters, grid results are refreshed but **the sum isn't updated**. For example, in the following Dojo I filter the column name with "contains" "1" or "2".

Example of my issue: [Dojo Kendo Sum with filters](https://dojo.telerik.com/AvuzINIq/2)

Any clue on what's happening or what I am doing wrong? How can I get the total to be refreshed?

Second question for my understanding:
How do the filters work with the datasource? Do they clone my initial datasource and keep only the desired results? So that would mean I am maybe not working with the right dataSource after the filters are applied?